# Python(3.8.2) - convert selenium(3.141.0) web element special character to string

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, special-characters

I'm trying to convert web element to a string in a sort of beginner crawler/bot program.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/against-the-gods/atg-chapter-1')
chapter_content = browser.find_elements_by_id('chapter-content')
with open('ATG.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for i in chapter_content:
        fp.write(i.text)
browser.quit()
```

It's all going well , as the text is being written, but whenever a character such as '!' or '-' is encountered the output just shows �

For example;
The intended output should be

```
Chapter 1 - Yun Che, Xiao Che
```

But it displays,

```
Chapter 1 � Yun Che, Xiao Che
```

Help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
open('ATG.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

instead of

```
open('ATG.txt', 'w'')
```